# How program a pause when automatically dialing a conference call number with Skype

Tags: skype

I am sure I am not the only one that asked this question.

We have a daily conference call that takes place in a foreign country, too early to attend so I decided to use Skype and record it automatically.
I use Task Scheduler

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"/callto:+XXXXXXXXXX,,,125
```

The dialer is supposed to dial the XX number and wait a few seconds (the ",") then dial the 125 access code.

Unfortunately Skype doesn't accept the "," pause

Any solutions ?

Comment: [Oft requested](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Pause-option-when-dialing/td-p/25354), never implemented AFAIK. If you use a Mac, maybe [this](http://blog.xam.dk/?p=214) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a 'P' should pause the dialing for 2 seconds.
This works in most dialing programs.

I think the 'P' would be in place of the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Pause4Skype](http://pause4skype.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/)

This is Skype plugin that allows to dial extension automatically.